# What is the most efficient way to find the root of a complex function in Sympy (a Python library for symbolic mathematics)?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, sympy

I am using the root_scalar function from the scipy.optimize module to find the root of a complex function defined in sympy. However, the function takes around 15-20 seconds to return the root, and I need to find a way to speed up this computation. Is it possible to convert the entire sympy function to scipy for faster processing, or is there any other way to optimize this process and reduce the computation time?

```
from sympy.stats import Gamma, density, cdf, E, variance
from sympy import Symbol, pprint, simplify
import numpy as np

l = 7 
m = 30
p = 17
w = 6 
K = 500 
c = 6 
h = 0.1 

mean = 500
std = 296


def calculate_mean(days):
  return mean*days

def calculate_std(days):
  return std*np.sqrt(days)
  
def calculate_mean_std(days):
  mean = calculate_mean(days)
  std = calculate_std(days)
  return mean, std

mean_m, std_m =  calculate_mean_std(m)
mean_l, std_l = calculate_mean_std(l)

shape_m = (mean_m/std_m)**2
scale_m = std_m**2/mean_m

shape_l = (mean_l/std_l)**2
scale_l = std_l**2/mean_l

k = Symbol("k", positive=True)
theta = Symbol("theta", positive=True)
x = Symbol("x")
X = Gamma("z", k, theta)

P = density(X)(x)
C = cdf(X, meijerg=True)(x)


cdf_m_symb = C.subs([(theta, scale_m) , (k, shape_m)])
cdf_l_symb = C.subs([(theta, scale_l) , (k, shape_l)])

pdf_m_symb = P.subs([(theta, scale_m) , (k, shape_m)])
pdf_l_symb = P.subs([(theta, scale_l) , (k, shape_l)])

max_Q = np.ceil(mean*(m+l)).astype(int)

def g(r: float) -> float:
    result = sp.N(-p + (p + w * cdf_m_symb.subs(x, max_Q)) * cdf_l_symb.subs(x, r) + \
                  w * sp.Integral(cdf_l_symb * pdf_m_symb.subs(x, (r + max_Q - x)), (x, 0, r)))
    return result

from scipy.optimize import root_scalar
import sympy as sp
import time

start_time = time.time()

r0 = 200  # initial estimate for the root
bracket = (-10, 5000)  # the upper and lower bounds of where the root is
solution = root_scalar(g, x0=r0, bracket=bracket)
print(solution)  # info about the convergence
print("Results: ",solution.root)  # the actual number

end_time = time.time()
print("Time taken:", end_time - start_time)
```

Here is the output from the above code

```
converged: True
flag: 'converged'  
function_calls: 10
iterations: 9
root: 3966.9429368680453
Results: 3966.9429368680453
Time taken: 13.81236743927002
```

I have provided the code that I am currently using and the output that it produces. Any suggestions or examples of how to optimize this process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is `lamdify` but it doesn't work with expressions containing Integral: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19641

Answer (score 0):

Compute the integral numerically, tabulate g(x) and interpolate x(g). Then your root-finding is nothing but evaluating a spline at a given point. Can't get any faster then that.